# Visual Studio keeps running the old build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a simple Silverlight program that displays a bunch of images. I modified it do display more images, but it when I hit "run without debugging" is keeps running the old build with fewer images. When I copy the code into a new project and run it, it works fine for the first time, but then each subsequent change is not displayed. What could be the problem? I'm using Visual Web Developer 2008 Express.

Comment: Does everything work properly if you manually build the project? From the "Build" menu, click "Rebuild Solution". Then try to run your project. Which version do you see?

Comment: @Cody: It's still the old version. But when I build it and run the generated TestPage.html, it's the new version.

Comment: So, the build is working properly because you can execute the built files manually? The problem is just that Visual Studio is starting the old version even after a rebuild?

Answer (score 23):

Always check "Configuration Manager" option on "Build" menu in Microsoft Visual Web Developer. The checkBox "build" has to be checked, otherwise it won't build.

Happened to me, I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 12):

I just had this happen to me in VS 2013 for Web. Had to change the Project URL in:

**"Project properties"**
 **"Web"** tab
  **"Servers"**

To a different localhost number and recreate Virtual directory.

Before my Project URL was:

```
http://localhost:55487/
```

I changed it to:

```
http://localhost:55488/
```

Then clicked **"Create Virtual Directory"**.

Would like to know why this happened in the first place.

Comment: This.    Thank you.  Spent hours trying to track down what was happening, and this is the only thing that fixed this issue for me.  I'm also not sure why this was happening, but would love to know.

Comment: I changed my source code folder and I had this issue. When I made this change it was reset and it worked. Thanks Adyson

Answer (score 4):

I found that I had to close all open instances of Visual Studio before I got it working again

Comment: This. I also deleted the /bin and /obj folders. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This happens because your cache memory is full. just go to you bin and obj folder and delete all the temporary files. Now it will run properly.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Deleted bin, obj and temp internet files.

Comment: Worked for me!!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a caching issue (webbrowser / proxy).

To fool the browser try to embed the xap file with an additional parameter that changes every time you open the plugin:

```
<param name="source" value="ClientBin/BubuApp.xap?<%=Guid.NewGuid().ToString() %>"/>
```

If this don't help, try to clean the project (delete obj / bin folders & xap file).

Answer (score 2):

I used to suffer this. All of this used to be (for me) a folder's contents issue.

Maybe you can check this:

- Delete `%windir%\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0xxx\Temporary`
- IIS Express: even if you change the output file for compiled results, you will see in `applicationhost.config` that many times IISExpress is really "looking" to the default `bin` folder of your project.
- It is even possible that you have different configurations for **Debug** or **Release**, so maybe IIS is looking `BIN` with **Release** code, and you are now compiling in **Debug** to another folder, do you understand me?

Answer (score 2):

I was also suffering from this issue and none of the suggestions worked. I was building a Office.js add-in and debugging was with IIS Express.
What fixed the issue for me was deleting files in
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET`

Actually, I went ahead and and deleted the entire `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp` folder out of spite :)

Comment: I'm also building an Office add-in and Mick's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue and while some of the fixes above helped temporarily, the one that worked for me was to remove the history and caching in Internet Options.

Go into Internet Option (also available in VS via Tools > options > Environment > Web Browser > Internet Explorer Options).

On the General tab click Settings in the Browsing History section.

- On the Temporary Internet Files page select Every time I start
  Internet Explorer
- On the History tab set the Days to keep history to 0
- On the Caches and Database tab make sure Allow website caches and
  databases is NOT ticked.

I'm not sure if all of the above are required, but I've made a number of changes to files and so far they have been reflected straight away in the dynamic versions without any noticeable performance problems.

I've also since realised if I set 'Every time I visit the webpage' instead of 'Every time I start Internet Explorer' I don't have to stop and restart the project to see the changes. Which is how it should be!

Comment: I'm building an Office add-in and this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me too. Well i dont know the exact reason for this behavior. But when i close the visual C express 10 and then open again and build it builds the new saved file. I guess it still hangs on to the old file when there is an error in some debug mode or something.

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop all incntance of VS.
2. Delete all /bin, not just /bin/Debug. All /bin
3. Remove user option .suo file in solution dir. It will create on self.
4. Remove all restore windows point
5. Stop IIS.
   6 Start IIS after 1 minutes.
6. Rebuild solution, Buid projects

It happing on me too. Very nasty. You may restart your computer.
Check for global asembly dll.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete folder 'Release' in project with old code build.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and none of the answers were working for me. It turns out that building the ASP.Net project did not build the Silverlight project, so running without debugging didn't update the Silverlight.

Fix: Right click the Asp.Net project. Build Dependencies > Project Dependencies. Check the Silverlight project. Now building should work.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a web application, change the Project URL with a new port number.

Example :

Change from `http://localhost:3688/`

To `http://localhost:36881/`

To do this:

> 1. Navigate to Project properties -> Web
> 2. Change the URL
> 3. Hit "Create Virtual Directory"
> 4. Finally, Build and RUN

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in a web site.
The site referenced 1 of the projects in the solution, and changes to it would not reflect in the debug.
Issue was a third project was referencing an outdated dll of the same same referenced project.
I removed the project and all references in other projects and readded and re-referenced everything and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check you haven't got two versions of whichever file you're updating (one for one group of users, one for a different group of users).

Answer (score 0):

In my case(VS 2015) it was because of the missing dll in the .exe directory... I made a "clean solution", then additionally deleted all bin and obj folders' contents. Reason to do so was VS keeping to load old dll build. Solution was to select folder of the running debug config, i.e. everytime I rebuild project destination location with dll and a reference to it stays with warning mark for some time until intellitrace does its job. After doing the setup mentioned above, I still have to do a manual rebuild on a project that generates a dll into specified dir. Pressing F5 does nothing, I don't have time to find out why... Main thing is its working for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this recently too and I didn't see the answer here. I was changing an MMI to get rid of redundant buttons, and they didn't go away.

Really old legacy code. To make it keep user settings - like language - someone had made it keep the Settings. I was not allowed to change this, they want it like that.

To get rid of the old settings and allow new ones:

open regedit

navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER - Software - MyProject - SubProject

here you see Recent File List and Settings.
Delete Settings completely - don't worry, it will make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check is there any old .tlb file present in someother folder. In my case i was using the .tlb file generated using .NET dll and then created the .tlb file using RegAsm. I tried to use the .tlb file in vb6 code, it still refers old code only. After a long search i found same .tlb file older version found in Visual Studio\VB98 folder. I removed it then it worked fine. This may not be relevent for this issue but could give you another way of thinking

Answer (score -1):

There is a scroll bar at the top which has 3 options:

- `debug`
- `release`
- `configuration manager`

Make sure `release` is selected.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When writing an answer, you may want to explain why you think your answer is correct, as it may be the case it is not targeting exactly the same problem and the explanation may help to see why.

Comment: I do not know about Silverlight, but normally in Visual Studio you can run without debugging both the release and debug versions. There are two things: 1) the debugging info being linked-in to the application, and 2) the way the application is started - either normally, or in the debugger. Therefore, you can run without debugging also the "debug" version of the program.

Answer (score -1):

I had to clear browsing data and it worked in my case