# Visual Studio not updating build

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2013

I'm creating a project in VS Express 2013 at the moment, but I've noticed my builds no longer include any of my new content. By that I mean it keeps building the same old project again and again, and not actually adding anything to the build. When I try closing and re opening VS, all my changes are still there in the designer and the .cs files, but building still gives no updates. I'm building using the default settings, using the debug build setting.

I've also tried doing what was mentioned here: [Visual Studio keeps running the old build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699418/visual-studio-keeps-running-the-old-build)

But the build checkbox has been checked, so that isn't an issue.

Any clue whats up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

When trying to run a project that's out of date, Visual Studio will ask you if you would like to build it. There's also a checkbox that says "Do not show this dialog box again".

[image]

If you check that dialog box and then select "no", you'll encounter this exact problem. Visual Studio will no longer rebuild projects after you make changes to them, and it won't prompt you to rebuild them.

To fix this, you'll want to go to **Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run**.

[image]

Make sure that the **Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run** option is **unchecked** and that the **On Run, when projects are out of date** option is set to **Prompt to build**.

Comment: But what will the code required in order to compile with the startup and dependencies in VS2017 and 2019?

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, just figured it out, but I'll leave this up for anyone encountering the same problems.

After going under the build menu, then selecting "Rebuild solution", my project was built properly, and simply selecting build actually builds the latest project now. It must've been some glitch that made VS think I hadn't made any changes, but this fixes it.