# VS Code won't compile most recently saved version of code

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

Whenever I make a change and save it, VS code won't run the most recently saved version of the code - it runs it as if it weren't saved. I have to close and reopen VS code for it to compile correctly. This is rather annoying and time-consuming. Is it possible that it is the extension for the language (Julia) and not VS Code that is causing this? Version info is below.

[Visual Studio keeps running the old build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699418/visual-studio-keeps-running-the-old-build) has something similar for Microsoft Visual Web Developer but I cannot check build under configuration manager (I can't even find those settings). Please help because I have an assignment I must write in VS Code due at midnight.

Version: 1.64.2 (user setup)
Commit: f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326
Date: 2022-02-09T22:02:28.252Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22000

Comment: Are you using Revise?

Comment: https://timholy.github.io/Revise.jl/stable/

Comment: @phipsgabler I don't know what you mean. Edit: Just saw the github link from Francis King